# Connect the Azure SQL Server Database with Active Directory Password using python (Got error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect the Azure, SQL Server Database using Active Directory Password with python. But i got the below error.

Please check the below error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "database_test.py", line 11, in main
    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+serverName+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+dbName+';UID='+User_name+';PWD='+ password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant could not be found. Install it from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Link Id=234947. If it is already present, repair the installation. [2].  (2) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (2); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]In
valid connection string attribute (0)')
```

Please Check the Below code:-

```
import pyodbc

def main():
    serverName = "<ServerName>"
    dbName = "<DatabaseName>"
    User_name = '<UserName>'
    password = '<Password>'

    driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+serverName+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+dbName+';UID='+User_name+';PWD='+password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    data = cursor.execute("select * from dbo.test;")
    allData = data.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    for i in allData:
        print(i)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there any way to resolve the above problem?

Is it possible to connect azure sql server Database using pyodbc with Active Directory Password authentication? if possible what is the proper way to connect the Azure Sql Server Database with Active directory Password?

Comment: you have all what you need in the error message

Comment: @LinPy I have checked the error message. I got one link from that error. I have already installed it then i got the same error

Comment: @AkshayGodase I tested your code with my Azure sql database, there's no error.

Comment: @LeonYue But which type of authentication you have used means Active Directory Password or SQL Server authentication

Comment: @AkshayGodase I also used the Active Directory Password authentication. Please see my answer.

Comment: @LeonYue Can you please share me your code and which steps you have used? Because i tried it on the machine, but I got the above error.

Comment: @AkshayGodase Yes, I post  my code in my answer, did you see that? I just followed the document.

Comment: @LeonYue Yes, I got your code. But whenever I am installing **Microsoft Active Directory Authentication Library for Microsoft SQL Server** that time I got the error. **Error is Installation of Active Directory Authentication Library for SQL Server failed because a higher version already exists on the machine. To proceed, uninstall the higher version and then run Active Directory Authentication Library for SQL Server Setup again.**

Comment: @LeonYue I uninstalled the previous version of **Microsoft Active Directory Authentication Library for Microsoft SQL Server** but then again same error

Comment: @LeonYue It's working fine now. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make you have installed the driver for Azure SQL database. You can download from this document [Quickstart: Use Python to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#linked-service-properties).

This document can give more guides with Python.

And according you error message, you have missed "The Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant". Please download and install it from the link provided for you:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Link Id=234947.

Here is my test Python code, I made some change that you can see more clearly:

```
import pyodbc

def main():
    serverName = "****.database.windows.net"
    dbName = "Mydatabase"
    User_name = '****@****.com'
    password = '****'
    Authentication='ActiveDirectoryPassword'
    driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+
                      ';Server='+serverName+
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+dbName+
                      ';UID='+User_name+
                      ';PWD='+ password+
                      ';Authentication='+Authentication)

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    data = cursor.execute("select * from dbo.tb1;")
    allData = data.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    for i in allData:
        print(i)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Note: I use ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Serve in my computer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested the above code and follows the above steps. It's working fine.